# window.open appearing behind webkit browsers, but not if I open a facebook or twitter page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using window.open() to open

http://twitter.com/share.. and 
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php...

to allow the user to post to their Facebook or Twitter accounts.

These popup windows appear correctly infront of my current Chrome or Safari windows.

However when I change the URL to another page on my current domain the popup window appears behind the current window instead of infront!? Same code, same function to open the window, just a different URL being passed to window.open().

I can't figure out why, I've tried everything, commenting out any javascript in the popup page or anything that might cause Chrome/Safari to think it's malicious.

Do these browsers detect the URL as being Facebook/Twitter and allow it to appear in front, and shove anything else to the back?

This is my function for opening the window

```
InfoOverlay.prototype.popupWindow = function(url, title, width, height) 
{
    var left = (screen.width/2) - (width/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2) - (height/2);
    var targetWin = window.open(
        url, 
        title, 
        'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, alwaysRaised=yes, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left
    );

    // These 2 lines added on suggestion from commenter below 
    // (doesn't fix issue)
    targetWin.blur();
    targetWin.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that those pages you are popping open have code in them to focus themselves (e.g. window.focus();)

You should be able to do that in your code in the page that pops the window open, just make sure you give your window a name, then do WindowName.focus();

This quick mockup in html seems to work in IE9, Chrome, FF4 but not Safari (3.x on Windows I have)

```
<script>
var myWin
</script>
<button onclick="myWin = window.open('about:blank', 'foo', 'height=200,width=200,modal=yes,alwaysRaised=yes');">Show Window</button>
<button onclick="myWin.blur();">Blur</button>
<button onclick="myWin.focus();">Focus</button>
```

Comment: yer tried that originally, no joy. I read somewhere they blocked .focus() some time ago for security reasons.

Comment: in reply to your edit I have put in my code in the original post to show you my code that doesn't bring it to the front still (but Twitter & Facebook URLs passed to it have no problems).